# how to render a react navigate instead of a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working on a validation form which fetches data from API. So, I have a state called "isLogged".

I initialiazed it as false then if the auth works, it changes to true.

So, I am trying to render an if-else statement with the if condition being the `"isLogged" === true` then I should navigate the user to Dashboard page

else when the "isLogged" is false, i render the whole form component,

but i dont have any idea how can i navigate the user between screens without onPress or rendering a component, i just would like to call a function to navigate or something else

***CODE:***

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: null,
      password: null,
      isLogged: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLogged) {
        # the command which navigate the user to Dashboard page
    } else {
      return (
        # The whole component code>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where you have use setState to make `isLogged` true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isLogged) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
    }


 return (
        # The whole component code>
      );

  }
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 0):

A better way to check these type of things is using Lifecycle hooks provided by react, because you make a clean render method as much as possible.
It's componentDidMount.

```
    class Login extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          username: null,
          password: null,
          isLogged: false,
        }
      }
     componentDidMount(){
       if (this.state.isLogged) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
        }
     }
      render() {
        return (
            # The whole component code>
         );
      }
    }
```

In Case you find error like, can find navigation of undefined, You will need to pass it via highercomponent "`WithNavigation`". It will add navigation object to your props.
Following is the code to use `WithNavigation`.

```
    import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
     class Login extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          username: null,
          password: null,
          isLogged: false,
        }
      }
     componentDidMount(){
       if (this.state.isLogged) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
        }
     }
      render() {
        return (
            # The whole component code>
         );
      }
    }
export default withNavigation(Login);
```

For more on lifecycle hooks, read this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)